# This command: ". .bashrc" has resulted in: “-bash: /usr/bin/whoami: Argument list too long” whenever I try to execute any command

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables, path

While following instructions at a forum post to install something over ssh at an external machine, I executed the following command without thinking:

```
. .bashrc
```

I have never seen the command before but am guessing (from having had a similar problem previously) that it recursively sources `~/.bashrc` because now I can't execute any commands.  When I login, I can't do anything.  I immediately get:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/whoami: Argument list too long
-bash: /usr/bin/cut: Argument list too long
-bash: /usr/bin/logger: Argument list too long
```

Unfortunately, I can't do what solved the problem when I had a similar problem in the past (login without using the bash shell by doing `ssh -t user@host /bin/sh` and then modify `~/.bashrc`) because there does not seem to be any problem with `~/.bashrc`.  It looks exactly the same as it did before I messed up.

Whatever I did, modifying `~/.bashrc` does not appear to be a fix.  Can anyone please suggest an alternative solution?

---

Here is `~/.bashrc`:

```
# .bashrc
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
       . /etc/bashrc
fi

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin/prog1:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin/prog2:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/prog2:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/prog2/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin/prog3/tools/newtool:$PATH

export PYTHONPATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/prog2:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: For starters, please add your complete `$HOME/.bashrc` to your question.

Comment: @ajgringo619, thank you.  I edited the question.

Comment: The problem does not come from your `.bashrc`, it comes from some other configuration file. This could be `/etc/bashrc` or something else. What is the output of the following command? `set -x; ulimit -a; echo foo; /bin/echo bar`

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', I pasted the command you suggested and the output as an edit to the question.  To do this, I had to login without using the bash shell by using the method I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the first set of `export` lines with this

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin"
[[ -d "$HOME/bin/prog1" ]] && PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin/prog1"
[[ -d "$HOME/bin/prog2" ]] && PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin/prog2"
[[ -d "$HOME/prog2" ]] && PATH="$PATH:$HOME/prog2"
[[ -d "$HOME/prog2/bin" ]] && PATH="$PATH:$HOME/prog2/bin"
[[ -d "$HOME/bin/prog3/tools/newtool" ]] && PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin/prog3/tools/newtool"
```

What was happening was that you were doubling up `$PATH` on every line (`$PATH` + new item + `$PATH`). Very strange.

In this replacement code each `[[ ... ]]` section ensures the corresponding directory exists before adding it to your `$PATH`. Not essential but certainly cleaner

Comment: Thank you!!  I am going to have to get some sleep and read your solution with a fresh brain to figure out what I was doing wrong, but it seems to have worked.  I can login on bash.  One thing that still doesn't work is that I still can't access "prog3" that I just installed.  I'm getting "No such file or directory" so still have an issue somewhere.  However, I'm happy to be able to login!!  Thank you very much.

Comment: yes, I accepted the answer.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's not necessary to export the variable everywhere: it's already exported.

Comment: @glennjackman ah yes. Thank you, code amended

Comment: you can also use `&& [[ ! "$PATH" =~ "$HOME/bin/prog1" ]]` to prevent a directory from being added to $PATH if it's already in it.    e.g. something like `for d in dir1 dir2 dir3 ; do [[ -d "$d" ]] && [[ ! "$PATH" =~ "\<$d\>" ]] && PATH="$PATH:$d" ; done`   (`\<` and `\>` are the ERE equivalents to PCRE's `\b`).

Comment: @cas indeed, and in my own PATH amendments I have something very similar (but with `[[ ! ":$PATH:" =~ ":$d:" ]]`

Comment: If the length of the `PATH` variable caused an "argument list too long" error, I'm betting that there is at least one environment variable that is _absolutely huge_.  Alternatively, that the user has an obsessive tendency to source `.bashrc` or related files many, many, many times.

Comment: @Kusalananda its length doubled up five times

Comment: On an Ubuntu system I have, I need to double up `PATH` between 12 and 14  times to hit that limit (depending on the length of the path I start with).  They must have started with a `PATH` that was about 6 KB long.

Comment: Remember they started with "_I executed the following command without thinking_", so they doubled up again. Assuming we're doing five doubles per invocation of `.bashrc`, from 80 bytes that gets me to ~80kB. One more doubling would do it.

Comment: @roaima, that doesn't still explain how they get the same problem on every login... Unless they manually source `.bashrc` by hand every time. But they already accepted this answer, so I guess the issue was in their `.bashrc` anyway.

Answer (score 7):

`. .bashrc` would run the contents of `.bashrc` in the current shell. Usually, you don't need to do that, since `.bashrc` is read by the shell when it starts, but if you make modifications to it and want to reload them, you might do that.

But doing that in one interactive shell shouldn't affect other shells you start on later logins.

---

What you have there in `.bashrc`, is somewhat odd, though:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin/prog1:$PATH
            ^^^^^                                  ^^^^^
```

Note how you're putting the old `$PATH` to the start *and* end of the new `PATH`, five different times. By my count, that would put the original `$PATH` there 32 times. That's not too bad, but if that has been done when the shell starts, your `$PATH` would now be some thousands of characters, and if you then do the same thing again, it might end up being far longer than 100 kB. Starting with my `$PATH` of 74 chars, running those assignments twice gives a string of 172 kB.

And that might be a problem: Linux has limit of 128 kB for the length of a single command line argument (in addition to a limit for the whole lot). Environment variables and command line arguments are passed similarly on `execve()`, so presumably the same limit applies to both, and hence `PATH`.

Comment: thank you for explaining that.  I just tried removing the line (in the non-bash shell) and then logged in in bash.  Unfortunately, I still have the same problem.  The line did exist before today.